# heading in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer

I have a question regarding the sudden change of heading when I try to print my bibliography. On each page I'm assigned to have a certain heading, only on a few pages there is a different one, or none.
For the pages I didn't need this heading I used a `\thispagestyle{empty}` command, and I only need a different heading on the first page, so I used the `\title` command, everywhere else, this is the command I used:

```
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[L]{\textbf {\color{gray} AGYS – Anglické gymnázium a SOŠ, s.r.o.}}
   \fancyhead[R]{\textbf {\color{gray} \thepage}}
   \vspace*{-1.1cm}
  \color{gray} \hrule
  \color{black}
```

Now, when I use the

```
\printbibliography[
    heading=bibintoc,
    title={SEZNAM POUŽITÉ LITERATURY}
]
```

command, my bibliography prints to two separate pages, this causes only one of the pages to contain the hrule in the heading, the other one doesn't have it.
How can I fix this so that the heading stay consistent through my work and there is a hrule in both pages where my bibliography is printed?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).